# Como diferenciar um EditText com o mesmo nome e o mesmo id?

Tags: android

```
public void criaForm(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        linearLayout.addView(et);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        linearLayout.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

Criei vários `EditTexts` dentro de um `for`, com isso eles têm o mesmo nome e id, existe alguma forma onde eu possa diferenciá-los? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Cara... Não ta claro sua pergunta... Tente se expressar melhor e coloque alguns pedaços de código pra que possamos ajudar você!

Comment: Olá, eu só queria diferenciar um EditText do outro sem ser pelo nome dele ou pelo id. Coloquei um pedaço do meu código onde eu crio ele. No meu código eu tenho 5 et. Eu queria por exemplo, quando clicar no segundo et, saber que cliquei nele.

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer `View` Android tem um atributo chamado `tag` ao qual pode ser usando para adicionar informação extra em uma `View`.

Um exemplo de sua utilização é o seguinte:

```
View view = new View(contexto);
Object objeto = new Object();
view.setTag(objeto);

Object objectDaTag = view.getTag();
```

E, já que `EditText` é filho de `View` também pode se aproveitar desse recurso. Como por exemplo:

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setTag(objeto);
Object objetoDaTag = et.getTag(); // se atribuído outra classe deve ser feito o cast
```

[Documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Obrigado pela respostas, mas já tentei com Tag e tive o mesmo problema do id, o EditText "pega" somente o valor da última Tag.

Comment: E se gerar IDs únicos para esses EditText resolve seu problema?

Comment: Perguntei isso porque creio que você não está atribuindo IDs incrementados para prevenir conflito com os IDs da classe R.

Comment: Eu gerei, usei o contador do for concatenado com outro número "(i+5)", o id fica único que testei isso colocando todos dentro de um ArrayList, o problema que estou tendo é para usar o textWatcher, eu tentei colocando todos os editTexts dentro de um ArrayList de EditText mas só funciona se eu setar o valor do editText na mão "listaEditText.get(posicao)" ,eu precisaria de clicar no editText e ele me retornar algum valor que pudesse diferencia-lo dos outros

Comment: Estou criando tudo dinamicamente, não estou usando xml para nada.

Comment: Não conheço outra forma de identificar uma View de maneira única e eficiente senão com id.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu problema é diferenciar dois EditTexts e nem `id` nem `tag` te satisfazem, tire proveito do mecanismo de herança e polimorfismo de Java e crie uma classe com um atributo a mais

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    ...

}
```